# Socket data corrupted during TCP/IP transfer

Tags: c, sockets

When i send data over a pre-connected TCP-IP socket, I see that the data is getting corrupted.

### Example:

Station1 is sending data to Station2. I have printed the data, before sending (at S1) and after receiving (at S2). Below is the message:

S1: 
Data sent is `ACK`
S2:
Data received is `AC�����`

Not sure what is the problem. I have even cleared the char-buffer before sending the data (at S1) and before receiving (at S2).

Any hint/info for the above would be of great help.

Comment: Post some code, we're not psychic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually the result of something like:

```
/* BAD CODE */
const char* ack = "ACK";
err = write( sockfd, ack, strlen( ack )); /* sender */
/* ... */
char buf[SOME_SIZE]
readb = read( sockfd, buf, SOME_SIZE ); /* receiver */
printf( "%s", buf );
```

The problem with the code above is that sender writes only three (3) bytes to the socket. That does not include string zero-terminator. Then the receiver gets the data and either does not check system call return value at all or/and blindly prints the received data. The `printf` will print everything until it finds zero-valued byte in memory.

#### Edit:

Based on your comments I think you are assuming that one [`send(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/send.2.html) over TCP socket should result in one [`recv(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/recv.2.html) on the other end with corresponding number of bytes (I'm guessing this is what you mean by "number of bytes read being wrong"). This is not the case with TCP though. You have to treat the socket as a stream that can give you arbitrary-sized chunks of what has been sent to you. It's your job to put them back together and recognize application message boundaries. This simply means you always read from a socket in a loop (not counting non-blocking designs with [`select(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) and friends - that's a separate topic).

Two accepted application-level protocol designs are:

- Communicate via pre-defined fixed-length messages - this way you read until you get that many bytes from the socket. Simple.
- Include message type and/or message length into the message itself - this is usually done with fixed-length message header that is followed by varying message payload. Read until you get full header then switch/dispatch/continue reading depending on type/length.

Don't forget about [endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) - networks like [network byte order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_byte_order#Endianness_in_networking).

Comment: Yes Nikolai, i have kept the systemcall output also, into a variable. However, i see that the no_of_bytes that iam getting on doing "recv" is still wrong.  I will try with, concatenating the sender text with "zero termination".

Comment: Hi Nikolai, it resolve thed the problem. I was send/recieving based on the string length based and not on sizeof(buf), which was the culprit, I changed it to sizeof(buf) while sending/receiving. It resolved the issue. However, not related to above problem, I see another discrepancy, which i will post it as a new question. Thanks for the clarification given above.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you receive the whole message at once? Since TCP is a stream-based protocol, the data you read on Station2 can come into small chunks of data. You have to look at how much data the recv() function put into your buffer.

For example, your first call to recv() can come up with "AC"
and then, the next call may give you the rest of the data "K"

Answer (score 0):

On the client side I send a string over to a socket:

```
char message[200];

/*string to be sent*/
strcpy(message, "Hi PQRS, How are you!?");

/*send string to server's socket*/
if( send(socket_desc , message , strlen(message)+1 , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
puts("Data Sent\n");
```

Notice how I pass

> 'strlen(message) + 1'

to allow for the delimiter i.e. '\0' 
instead of

> 'strlen(message)'

It ensures the end of the string and that no extra data gets added.

This would work irrespective of the size of the character array at the server side provided it is equal to or bigger than the incoming string so as to accommodate it.