# Client only receiving partial data back from the server via a socket in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Brand new to StackOverflow and definitely brand new to figuring out how to get sockets to work in C. Here's what I'm trying to do: I need to create two programs where one acts as a "daemon" (not actually, you just launch it first and it runs in the background) that listens on a specified port, and then another program that attempts to send information -- via that port -- from a plaintext file, along with the name of a "key" file that should be used to encrypt it. The daemon program connects to the (let's call it client) program, forks off a new process, accepts the information, encrypts the text accordingly, and then sends it back to the client program to be stored in a file.

This last part is where I'm having trouble. I've been able to successfully transfer all of the data from the client to the daemon program, and even successfully encrypt it; I tried storing the info into a temp file to see how it was coming out and everything looked as it should. But when I try to send the information back -- it's worth noting that I'm trying to send it back in chunks as the daemon program is encrypting it and therefore potentially still receiving info -- the client only receives a fraction of the data before the connection is seemingly closed and the process is finished.

Sorry for the lengthy post, just trying to be as detailed as possible. I tried searching for some posts regarding this topic and I did find [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259722/socket-data-corrupted-during-tcp-ip-transfer), but it wasn't quite the same issue (plus the suggested fixes were things I already tried). Below is what I think is the pertinent code. This is only my current set up, so certain aspects might just be random bits from different approaches I've tried, e.g. the shutdown on write on the client side is a recent addition that doesn't appear to have made a difference. I've tried a number of different things to make this work over the past week, so if any of the suggestions that come in are things that I've tried, I'll let you folks know. Thanks in advance!

Client:

```
//Create socket, check for success
//
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "socket creation failed");
        exit(1);
    }
//Create address structure for socket to connect to

    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);  
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int success;
    success = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server));
    if(success == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not find port, failed to connect socket\n");
        exit(2);
    }

//IF all is well, open up the plaintext file for extracting data

    FILE* ptextSend = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    int totalNeeded;
    rewind(ptextSend);
    fseek(ptextSend, 0L, SEEK_END);
    totalNeeded = ftell(ptextSend);
    totalNeeded = totalNeeded - 1;
    rewind(ptextSend);
//First, send key path

    send(sockfd, keypath, sizeof(keypath), 0);

//Then, send contents of file
    int n = 0;
    char buffer[1000];
    while(n < totalNeeded){
    fgets(buffer, 1000, ptextSend);
    printf("right now buffer is %s\n", buffer);
    n = n + (send(sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0));
    }
    shutdown(sockfd, 1);
//Attempt to receive encrypted info back    
    n=1;
    while(n != 0){
    char* newBuff[1000];
    n = recv(sockfd, newBuff, sizeof(newBuff) - 1, 0);
    if(n!=0)
    fprintf(stdout, "this is the client: %s\n", newBuff);
    }
```

Daemon/Server code:

```
//Create socket
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Server error: failure to create socket.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

//Create address for socket
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

//Bind socket to port using address struct
    int bindSuccess = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server));
    if(bindSuccess == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Server error: bind call failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

//Set socket to listen
    int listenSuccess = listen(sockfd, 5);
    if(listenSuccess == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Server error: listen call failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

//Accept next client connection
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t client_length = sizeof(client_addr);
    int client_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, &client_length);
    if(client_sockfd == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Server error: accept call failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
pid_t pid = fork();

if(pid < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error forking process on connection.\n");
    exit(1);
}
if(pid == 0){
//First receive key path
    char keybuff[100];
    recv(client_sockfd, keybuff, sizeof(keybuff),0);
    FILE* theKey = fopen(keybuff, "r");

    char buffer[1000];
    int n = 1;

    while(n != 0){
    n = recv(client_sockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1, 0);

    strtok(buffer, "\n");
    char* newString = encrypt(buffer, theKey);
    send(client_sockfd, newString, sizeof(newString) - 1, 0);

    }

    if(n == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Server error: failed to read from socket.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fclose(theKey);
    close(client_sockfd);
    close(sockfd); 

    return 0;
}else
    return 0;

}
```

What I should be getting back is "right now buffer is: THE RED GOOSE FLIES AT MIDNIGHT STOP" followed by its encrypted version, so 36 characters of gibberish (occasionally broken up with "this is the client" and a newline). Instead, the total output is:

right now buffer is THE RED GOOSE FLIES AT MIDNIGHT STOP

this is the client: BPZDOSZ

...so just seven characters worth of data and then it exits (successfully).

Comment: What do the several calls to `recv()` return?

Comment: Does `encrypt()` `0`-terminate its result?

Comment: How do you prevent the `recv()` call that reads the key from also reading parts of the file that are sent afterwards?

Comment: `sizeof(newString)` returns the size of the pointer `newString` which is either 4 or 8 depending on the bit width of your platform.

Comment: Come on, run this code inside a debugger, tracing it line by line, and while doing so inspect each and every value whether its contains what it should.

Comment: Same size-of issue in the client for this `sizeof(newBuff)`.

Comment: Also not at least for the sake of efficient debugging: ***Do test*** the outcome of ***all relevant*** function calls as detailed as possible. Read the documentation to learn what detailed info the functions provide on success or failure. Log this.

Comment: Comment 1: You're doing `while (n != 0) { n = recv(...)`: so if `recv` *does* return 0, you still execute the rest of the loop. Should restructure the code. One way (common in C) is:   `while ((n = recv(....)) > 0) {`  (`> 0` because `-1` is the error return from `recv`)

Comment: Comment 2: You should explicitly null-terminate your buffer -- following the `recv` -- before calling `strtok`. Otherwise, `strtok` may clobber whatever follows `buffer` on the stack.

Comment: Comment 3: TCP does not preserve message boundaries. So, even though you're sending the file-to-be-encrypted a line at a time, the `recv` calls on the daemon side will almost certainly *not* obtain only a single line with each call.

Comment: Agh, it was the sizeof(newString) part. My bad. Thanks so much, alk/everybody! I'd upvote it if I had the ability to do so...

Comment: Please, post full working examples.  As such, your code snippet can have the problem erased once posted (as you **don't know** what the problem with the code is, you can accidentally erase it while extracting a not-working snippet ---that we have to rearrange again to make it executable---)